# Soft G might be as in

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Soft G might be as in **general** and hard G as in **goat**. Is that what you are asking?

[Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reason-behind-the-names-soft-and-hard-g.4015839/#post-20604251)

---

I found those sentences on Google.
Does "be as" a shortened form of "*be pronounced as*" or does it mean "*exist, for example*"?

Comment: Some words might have been elided... it could have been more clear as "Soft G might be as it's sounded in *general* and hard G as the sound in *goat*. Is that what you are asking?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds idiomatic to me. Compare with the phrasing in [Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/pronunciation-guide-fr/letter-y):

> The first sound is as in English *syrup*, where *y* is a vowel with the same sound as [i]

The expression "as in" is used to make a clarification, and it's often used without any verb at all. In this context it means "Soft G might be the same sound that's in the word *general*". On the phone, someone might be spelling out a word and say "D as in *David*" so the person on the other end doesn't think it was "B as in *boy*" or "V as in *Victor*" (since this is about spelling, the sounds might not match: "U as in *umbrella*"). Here's yet [another example](https://www.myneworleans.com/hey-boo-new-orleans-colloquialisms/), where "as in" is used to introduce a sample sentence containing the previously mentioned phrase:

> **“Your mom ‘n’ ’em”**
> As in “Howz your mom ‘n’ ’em?”

Answer (score 0):

No, *be as* is not an established phrase.

The phrase *as in general* is a sort of adverbial, and is the complement of *is*.

Comment: What's the meaning of the "*as in*" in "as in general"?

Comment: "as" here means "in the same way as".

Comment: Is "Soft G might be as in **general**" a shortened form of "Soft G might be as (soft G is) in **general**" or "Soft G might be as (the **g**) in **general** (is)"?

Comment: I don't think it's a "shortened form", but those are other ways to say it.